# Can't find uploaded image after removing Cloudinary from MERN stack

Tags: mern, cloudinary

I made a ecommerce project for my study 6 months ago but now I need to remove Cloudinary from this MERN stack. My client has his own server and doesn't require Cloudinary. I changed the following code from user avatar to the following code and also need to do later in products:

```html
// Old code
const User = require('../models/userModel');
const asyncErrorHandler = require('../middlewares/asyncErrorHandler');
const sendToken = require('../utils/sendToken');
const ErrorHandler = require('../utils/errorHandler');
const sendEmail = require('../utils/sendEmail');
const crypto = require('crypto');
const cloudinary = require('cloudinary');

// Register User
exports.registerUser = asyncErrorHandler(async (req, res, next) => {

    const myCloud = await cloudinary.v2.uploader.upload(req.body.avatar, {
        folder: "avatars",
        width: 150,
        crop: "scale",
    });

    const { name, email, gender, password } = req.body;

    const user = await User.create({
        name, 
        email,
        gender,
        password,
        avatar: {
            public_id: myCloud.public_id,
            url: myCloud.secure_url,
        },
    });

    sendToken(user, 201, res);
});

// Login User
exports.loginUser = asyncErrorHandler(async (req, res, next) => {
    const { email, password } = req.body;

    if(!email || !password) {
        return next(new ErrorHandler("Please Enter Email And Password", 400));
    }

    const user = await User.findOne({ email}).select("+password");

    if(!user) {
        return next(new ErrorHandler("Invalid Email or Password", 401));
    }

    const isPasswordMatched = await user.comparePassword(password);

    if(!isPasswordMatched) {
        return next(new ErrorHandler("Invalid Email or Password", 401));
    }

    sendToken(user, 201, res);
});

// Logout User
exports.logoutUser = asyncErrorHandler(async (req, res, next) => {
    res.cookie("token", null, {
        expires: new Date(Date.now()),
        httpOnly: true,
    });

    res.status(200).json({
        success: true,
        message: "Logged Out",
    });
});

// Get User Details
exports.getUserDetails = asyncErrorHandler(async (req, res, next) => {
    
    const user = await User.findById(req.user.id);

    res.status(200).json({
        success: true,
        user,
    });
});

// Forgot Password
exports.forgotPassword = asyncErrorHandler(async (req, res, next) => {
    
    const user = await User.findOne({email: req.body.email});

    if(!user) {
        return next(new ErrorHandler("User Not Found", 404));
    }

    const resetToken = await user.getResetPasswordToken();

    await user.save({ validateBeforeSave: false });

    // const resetPasswordUrl = `${req.protocol}://${req.get("host")}/password/reset/${resetToken}`;
    const resetPasswordUrl = `https://${req.get("host")}/password/reset/${resetToken}`;

    // const message = `Your password reset token is : \n\n ${resetPasswordUrl}`;

    try {
        await sendEmail({
            email: user.email,
            templateId: process.env.SENDGRID_RESET_TEMPLATEID,
            data: {
                reset_url: resetPasswordUrl
            }
        });

        res.status(200).json({
            success: true,
            message: `Email sent to ${user.email} successfully`,
        });

    } catch (error) {
        user.resetPasswordToken = undefined;
        user.resetPasswordExpire = undefined;

        await user.save({ validateBeforeSave: false });
        return next(new ErrorHandler(error.message, 500))
    }
});

// Reset Password
exports.resetPassword = asyncErrorHandler(async (req, res, next) => {

    // create hash token
    const resetPasswordToken = crypto.createHash("sha256").update(req.params.token).digest("hex");

    const user = await User.findOne({ 
        resetPasswordToken,
        resetPasswordExpire: { $gt: Date.now() }
    });

    if(!user) {
        return next(new ErrorHandler("Invalid reset password token", 404));
    }

    user.password = req.body.password;
    user.resetPasswordToken = undefined;
    user.resetPasswordExpire = undefined;

    await user.save();
    sendToken(user, 200, res);
});

// Update Password
exports.updatePassword = asyncErrorHandler(async (req, res, next) => {

    const user = await User.findById(req.user.id).select("+password");

    const isPasswordMatched = await user.comparePassword(req.body.oldPassword);

    if(!isPasswordMatched) {
        return next(new ErrorHandler("Old Password is Invalid", 400));
    }

    user.password = req.body.newPassword;
    await user.save();
    sendToken(user, 201, res);
});

// Update User Profile
exports.updateProfile = asyncErrorHandler(async (req, res, next) => {

    const newUserData = {
        name: req.body.name,
        email: req.body.email,
    }

    if(req.body.avatar !== "") {
        const user = await User.findById(req.user.id);

        const imageId = user.avatar.public_id;

        await cloudinary.v2.uploader.destroy(imageId);

        const myCloud = await cloudinary.v2.uploader.upload(req.body.avatar, {
            folder: "avatars",
            width: 150,
            crop: "scale",
        });

        newUserData.avatar = {
            public_id: myCloud.public_id,
            url: myCloud.secure_url,
        }
    }

    await User.findByIdAndUpdate(req.user.id, newUserData, {
        new: true,
        runValidators: true,
        useFindAndModify: true,
    });

    res.status(200).json({
        success: true,
    });
});

// ADMIN DASHBOARD

// Get All Users --ADMIN
exports.getAllUsers = asyncErrorHandler(async (req, res, next) => {

    const users = await User.find();

    res.status(200).json({
        success: true,
        users,
    });
});

// Get Single User Details --ADMIN
exports.getSingleUser = asyncErrorHandler(async (req, res, next) => {

    const user = await User.findById(req.params.id);

    if(!user) {
        return next(new ErrorHandler(`User doesn't exist with id: ${req.params.id}`, 404));
    }

    res.status(200).json({
        success: true,
        user,
    });
});

// Update User Role --ADMIN
exports.updateUserRole = asyncErrorHandler(async (req, res, next) => {

    const newUserData = {
        name: req.body.name,
        email: req.body.email,
        gender: req.body.gender,
        role: req.body.role,
    }

    await User.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, newUserData, {
        new: true,
        runValidators: true,
        useFindAndModify: false,
    });

    res.status(200).json({
        success: true,
    });
});

// Delete Role --ADMIN
exports.deleteUser = asyncErrorHandler(async (req, res, next) => {

    const user = await User.findById(req.params.id);

    if(!user) {
        return next(new ErrorHandler(`User doesn't exist with id: ${req.params.id}`, 404));
    }

    await user.remove();

    res.status(200).json({
        success: true
    });
});
```

```html
// New code
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

// Function to upload an avatar and return the file path
const uploadAvatar = (avatarData) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        // Define the directory where avatars will be stored
        const avatarUploadDir = path.join(__dirname, '..', 'avatars');

        // Ensure the avatar directory exists; create if not
        if (!fs.existsSync(avatarUploadDir)) {
            fs.mkdirSync(avatarUploadDir);
        }

        // Generate a unique file name for the avatar
        const uniqueFileName = `${Date.now()}_${Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000)}.png`;

        // Construct the full file path
        const avatarFilePath = path.join(avatarUploadDir, uniqueFileName);

        // Decode the base64 avatar data and write to the file
        const avatarBuffer = Buffer.from(avatarData, 'base64');
        fs.writeFile(avatarFilePath, avatarBuffer, (err) => {
            if (err) {
                reject(err);
            } else {
                resolve(avatarFilePath);
            }
        });
    });
};

    const user = await User.create({
        name,
        email,
        gender,
        password,
        avatar: {
            file_path: avatarFilePath, // Use the uploaded file path
        },
    });
```

However, after making these changes,  I am getting avatarFilePath not defined everytime I try to upload and don't know where the uploaded image is being saved. Can anyone help me with this?

My GitHub project is: https://github.com/KeshavKris/Flipkart-Clone

Comment: Shouldn't it be found at `avatarFilePath`? Are you receiving some error?

Comment: Yeah I am getting avatarFilePath not defined everytime I try to upload

Comment: I assumed the variable existed, and I meant that maybe the file referenced by that variable doesn't exist. - if the variable itself doesn't exist, fix that first and then check if when the variable contains the path to an existing local file, if that solves it